# Google consent mode Beta not showing page_view on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

Possible duplicates:

- [Google Analytics Consent mode (beta) - Sends data but is not reflected on dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951848/google-analytics-consent-mode-beta-sends-data-but-is-not-reflected-on-dashbo)
- [Google Consent Mode from GTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669179/google-consent-mode-from-gtm)

I have followed the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/consent), but on Google Analytics dashboard I don't see any data in the real time mode.

```
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript>
         window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
         function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
             gtag('consent', 'default', {
                  'analytics_storage': 'denied',
                  'wait_for_update': 500
             });
      
             gtag('js', new Date());
             gtag('config', 'UA-1XXXXXXXX-');
     </script>
     </head>
```

If the "denied" value is updated to "granted", the data shows up on the Google Analytics dashboard. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, if the Analytics consent is denied, despite the interactions being sent to the Google Analytics servers, the data set in question (characterized by a parameter that identifies the consent method) is not collected / exposed in the reports. So it's normal that you don't see the data.

Comment: But then how are they able to see the active users, active pages. This is what even we want to achieve, but its not behaving same for us.

https://cookiemagic.eu/explainer-video-google-consent-mode-and-google-analytics/